# AWS S3 sending content as attachment

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a direct way after saving something in a S3 bucket to send the content as attachment by SNS (via email) or do i have create a lambda function in order to tell SNS, what i want to send?

`S3 bucket -> SNS -> Email` (my preferred way, if possible)
or is this not possible without lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event that S3 sends to Lambda, SNS or SQS only contains a reference to the item that was created, not the actual content.

If you want to pass on the content, you have to download it in whichever code responds to that event and then send it to your destination.

There is no mechanism that sends the content of a newly uploaded object to an SNS topic.

Comment: So i could use lamda to create a SNS topic with the content, correct?

Comment: Yes, you could use a Lambda function to send the content to an SNS topic, just beware of the maximum message size of 256kb.