# Send a table of data through sns

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm working on a lambda which does some processing and creates a pandas `DataFrame` as output. I want the contents of this dataframe to be mailed to users in form of a table. Can this be done thorugh Amazon SNS or do I need SES? We already have SNS setup for our project and using SES just for this seems a bit overkill.

Comment: Write the DataFrame to S3. Trigger another lambda which will download this file and send it via SNS. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66475678/aws-s3-sending-content-as-attachment

Comment: How do you expect your email to look when it is received? Would it just be plain text, or would it be formatted (eg HTML)? Also, who are these "users" -- are they staff, or customers? (Staff don't need things as pretty as customers!)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Users are staff members. I want the data to be in a simple html table nothing fancy.

Comment: One option is to put the pretty stuff in an Amazon S3 object and simply send them a link to the object via Amazon SNS. Otherwise, you'll need to somehow turn it into pretty HTML and use Amazon SES to send an email.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to provide a custom format for SNS emails and on top of that, the table columns won't line up as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254270/monospaced-font-with-amazon-sns).

So unfortunately if you want prettier emails you'd need to set up SES.